# Assembly file version management in Silverlight application

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, version

For version management purposes, I need to increase the version of the assembly file to verify the release version. The issue here is that if I increase the file assembly version, other referenced projects where that assembly is used are getting failures, because of the version mismatch.

I am unable to make out what is the proper way to manage the version of assembly files in such a case.

Any suggestions or guidance here is appreciated.

Comment: In this case, you cant increase the file assembly version, but you can track  the version by using other attribute of assembly file, for instance you can use the "AssemblyTrademark" attribute to track the version. In each release you can increase the version.

Eg- [assembly: AssemblyTrademark("1.1.1.7")]

Comment: @Sudharshan, Thank you, this give solution to our problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you cant increase the file assembly version, but you can track the version by using other attribute of assembly file, for instance you can use the "AssemblyTrademark" attribute to track the version. In each release you can increase the version.

```
Eg- [assembly: AssemblyTrademark("1.1.1.7")]
```